# MYSQL, Insert the numeric characters of a string in a column to another column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to clean the telephone numbers of a database so we can easily search for them. In the column TEL we have rows like:

```
654-598-5487
654.254.2456
(458)-5458789 e.3
```

I want to copy all those values to a new column where only the numeric characters are transferred:

```
6545985487
6542542456
45854587893
```

The new column (TEL_NO_FORMAT) is a big int and it only allows numbers, but if I execute something like this:

```
UPDATE CLIENTS set `TEL_NO_FORMAT` = `TEL`
```

It will only transfer the first numeric characters found and ignore the rest:

```
654
654
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is the `REGEXP_REPLACE`(MySQL 8.0+):

```
SELECT *, REGEXP_REPLACE(tel_no_format, '[^0-9]','') AS result
FROM clients
```

Answering the question in an update query

```
UPDATE CLIENTS SET TEL_NO_FORMAT = REGEXP_REPLACE(TEL, '[^0-9]','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the undesired char before

```
UPDATE CLIENTS set `TEL_NO_FORMAT` = replace(replace(replace(`TEL`, '.',''),'-',''),')','')
```

because some char (eg '-') are create problem during conversion ..

anyway rember that a big int can't manage properly eventual tel number 0 prefixed eg:

```
00453778988
```